# How did families parent in the Middle Ages?

Tags: middle-ages

The question is probably a subject for a book, but I am really curious: how did parenting look in the middle ages? How did the common folk bring up children? How were the children clothed, what was used instead of diapers?

Comment: This *may* be closed on the basis that you admit it is a book length question. I hope that we can find some short, incomplete answers.

Comment: "What did <historical people> use instead of diapers?" should be its own question, I think. There are some interesting answers across a range of cultures and time periods.

Comment: Google "cloth diapers". They are still used, even in the countries with real diapers available

Comment: Diapers, LOL. Rich people used swaddling. Poor people put babies and toddlers in the hay. In England middle class houses were carpeted and roof stuffed with a kind of hay called "thresh". Infants were just laid about in beds of the thresh. When they soiled it, it would be turned over, or when it got bad, it was thrown out and new thresh added. The cats would go up in the rafters and piss in the thresh, talk about stinky odor.